# AWS - Create AMI Using EC2 Instance Tags To Name The AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'm trying to do something I believe is so simple but I'm not a Python expert, so I need your help on this, let me show you what I'm trying to do:

I have this part of a code that I had found and is working very well, but I'm trying to change it a little bit:

```
AMIid = ec.create_image(InstanceId=instance['InstanceId'], Name="BKP - " + **instance['InstanceId']** + " from " + create_fmt, Description="Lambda created AMI of instance " + instance['InstanceId'] + " from " + create_fmt, NoReboot=True, DryRun=False)
```

I'm trying to add the TAG "Name" from my EC2 instances in the field "Name" of the new AMI that is being created, something like this:

```
AMIid = ec.create_image(InstanceId=instance['InstanceId'], Name="BKP - " + **Tags=[Key:"Name",'Value']** + " from " + create_fmt, Description="Lambda created AMI of instance " + instance['InstanceId'] + " from " + create_fmt, NoReboot=True, DryRun=False)
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

**Editing:** I've found a solution for this, maybe this is not the best way, but worked, follow what I've done so far:

Created a variable to get the EC2 Tag name:

```
nameTag = "".join([str(t.get('Value')) for t in instance['Tags'] if t['Key'] == 'Name'])
```

Then, included the "nameTag" variable to the code:

```
AMIid = ec.create_image(InstanceId=instance['InstanceId'], Name="BKP - " + **nameTag** + " from " + create_fmt, Description="Lambda created AMI of instance " + instance['InstanceId'] + " from " + create_fmt, NoReboot=True, DryRun=False)
```

Hope this could help more people that needs something like that!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be useful as this is already a 2 year old post but nontheless

```
details = ec.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance['InstanceId']])
            for tags in details['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags']:
                if tags['Key'] == "Name":
                    instance['Name'] = tags['Value']

            print("Instance Name:" + instance['Name'])
```

The above script will give you the name of the instance